# I'm trying to make a function to take user input of a palindrome. Why is it after I take input for one array, it automatically inputs the rest?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, syntax

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ROWS 6
#define LENGTH 30

int main (void)
{

    int wordcount[ROWS]; // Incraments word count. i.e. Word 1, Word 2, Word 3...
    char word[LENGTH]; // Stores users string

    for(int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("Word %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d %s", &wordcount[i], &word[0]); // Input ends here. Prints out the rest of the array with "no" values.
            i++;
        }
        if(i == 2)
        {
            printf("Word %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d %s", &wordcount[i], &word[1]);
            i++;
        }
        if(i == 3)
        {
            printf("Word %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d %s", &wordcount[i], &word[2]);
            i++;
        }
        if(i == 4)
        {
            printf("Word %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d %s", &wordcount[i], &word[3]);
            i++;
        }
        if(i == 5)
        {
            printf("Word %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d %s", &wordcount[i], &word[4]);
        }
        break;

    }

return 0;

}
```

I've tried multiple loops, changing syntax and placement, but nothing makes sense to me anymore. I AM NOT ALLOWED TO USE POINTERS, GLOBAL VARIABLES, OR ANY OTHER LIB FUNCTIONS BESIDES `scanf()`, `printf()`, `fgets()`, or `strlen()`. I have to make multiple functions to get user input, reverse the string, and find out whether or not it's a palindrome... but I can't seem to get past part 1.

Comment: A couple comments:  (1) Learn to indent your code properly.  Your `if` statements and their consequent statements are currently indented at the same level, which is very bad style and masks errors.  And (2) It looks like you're missing `{}` around your `if` bodies, but since you forgot to indent your code, it's not entirely clear which statements were meant to be part of the `if` bodies and which were not.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you, I've updated it - but I still have the same problem.

Comment: The chain of `if` statements is a bit strange, in that once one of them is executed, `i` is incremented and the rest will all be executed as well.  But it's also in a loop.  Do you really need all those `if` statements?  Can't you just input one word per loop iteration, then wait for the next loop iteration to get the next one?  Also, don't forget that C arrays begin at index `0`.

Comment: char word[] is a string so you read a string into word + 0, then word + 1.  Did you want array of strings?  Otherwise if you want to read  char use %c.  Also, you read a integer than a word, if you don't enter a number, scanf() fails repeatedly.

Comment: Also, the problem description is dumb... you need to use a pointer to read data via either `fgets()` or `scanf()`.

Comment: I think the whole purpose of this assignment is to not use pointers or "*" directly. I know I put it as the main function, but we're supposed to have 3 functions i.e getstring, revstring, and is_palindrome that will be called in main. Main showed here is really getstring. I don't know if that clarifies or not... @AllanWind

Comment: weemplewomple, Do not use `"%s"` without a width limit.  `scanf("%d %s" ...` --> `scanf("%d %29s" ...`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this by not entered an integer and only the string.  This means `scanf()` fails on the first and the subsequent attempts.  Here is a simplified version of your program with error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 6
#define LENGTH 29

#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main (void) {
    int wordcount[ROWS];
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf("Word %d: ", i + 1);
        int n = scanf(" %d %" str(LENGTH) "s", wordcount + i, word + i);
        if(n != 2) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
Word 1: 1 abcd
Word 2: cd
scanf failed
```

Not clear from the problem description what you are trying to do with word but it's probably incorrect as you write a string to position 0 of word, then the next word 2 at position 1 (overwriting part of word 1) etc.  Do you actually mean count of words or count of letters in the word?  For the latter use `strlen()`.

Comment: I edited in the headers and definitions so it makes more sense. I started "i" at 1 so when it prompts the user to input the character string, it says "Word 1:", then "Word 2:" and so on... I want the user to only be able to enter 5 words with a character count less than 30. I see that it makes no sense to put LENGTH the way I did now... sigh... so lost

Comment: You can start i at 1, if you want, but arrays start at 0 so then you do i-1 to access the array.  It's very common to start indices at 0 and, like I did, just +1 for display.  Please clarify what you want word to contain, and what wordcount is. @CraigEstey's solution is probably more cut and paste but  I answered your question on why the next scanf() happens right away.

Comment: @AllanWind Very nice programmatic code for width.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. Indexes should start from 0 and *not* 1
2. The `word` array needs to be 2D (*not* 1D)
3. That is, you want an *array* of words that has `ROWS` number of words and each word can be [up to] `LENGTH` characters.
4. A simple loop can get all words without any `if` statements
5. It's better to use `fgets` and `strlen` instead of `scanf` for input where you *prompt* the user

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS        5
#define LENGTH      100

int
main(void)
{

    // length of each word
    int wordcount[ROWS];

    // Stores users string
    char word[ROWS][LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        // prompt the user
        printf("Word %d: ", i + 1);
        fflush(stdout);

        // get the line with the word
        if (fgets(word[i],LENGTH,stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        // get the word length
        size_t len = strlen(word[i]);

        // strip newline
        if ((len > 0) && (word[i][len - 1] == '\n')) {
            word[i][len - 1] = 0;
            --len;
        }

        // save the length
        wordcount[i] = len;
    }

    // print the words
    for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  ++i)
        printf("Word %d is %d bytes: '%s'\n",i + 1,wordcount[i],word[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick... I's a rewrite not a refactoring.

Comment: Regardless if this person is nitpicking, they organized it in a way that's palatable. Which is appreciated. This makes a lot of sense. Also, it's not if I can copy and paste it as they use a function that I cannot. (Also that's just silly) so... Wow. I got to say. You know your shit, especially if you did that on purpose.

Comment: Last loop better as `for (int j = 0;  j < i;  ++j)` and use `j` in loop body.  This avoids trouble when `fgets(word[i],LENGTH,stdin) == NULL` is true.